How BigQuery avoids full-scan of an unpartitioned column?
I have an unpartitioned BigQuery table with some 425k rows scattered over 1-2 years.
I was about to partition this table by timestamp while I've observed an interesting phenomenon: the query already behaves as it would run on the partitioned table. E.g. the later is the timestamp, the less data process the query and quicker it runs:
SELECT meta FROM `project.dataset.table` where timestamp > '2024-07-09'
Bytes processed 3.25Mb

SELECT meta FROM `project.dataset.table` where timestamp > '2024-06-30'
Bytes processed 13Mb

SELECT meta FROM `project.dataset.table` where timestamp > '2024-06-15'
Bytes processed 26.81 MB

Question:
How the database can skip the scanning the complete meta column where it is neither partitioned nor clustered?
Is it a reliable behavior? Can I skip partitioning data on BQ at all and rely on BQ to scan only needed data?
My table is very efficiently compressed:
Total logical bytes 2.06 GB
Total physical bytes 86.6 MB

(it may related to the observed phenomenon, although I'm not sure)
Until now I was convinced that partitioning (partition pruning) and clustering are the only methods to avoid the full column scan.
Table specification:
bq show --format=prettyjson project:dataset.table
{
  "creationTime": "1660725581097",
  "etag": "PNomRWba1MQFgVDSGcrgiQ==",
  "id": "project:dataset.table",
  "kind": "bigquery#table",
  "lastModifiedTime": "1720490034640",
  "location": "region",
  "numActiveLogicalBytes": "2213392702",
  "numActivePhysicalBytes": "90803671",
  "numBytes": "2213392702",
  "numCurrentPhysicalBytes": "90803671",
  "numLongTermBytes": "0",
  "numLongTermLogicalBytes": "0",
  "numLongTermPhysicalBytes": "0",
  "numRows": "425332",
  "numTimeTravelPhysicalBytes": "0",
  "numTotalLogicalBytes": "2213392702",
  "numTotalPhysicalBytes": "90803671",
  "schema": {
    "fields": [
      {
        "description": "Feature extraction id",
        "mode": "REQUIRED",
        "name": "id",
        "type": "STRING"
      },
      {
        "description": "Entity id (hash system identity).",
        "mode": "REQUIRED",
        "name": "entity_id",
        "type": "STRING"
      },
      {
        "description": "Collector (check) run id.",
        "mode": "REQUIRED",
        "name": "collector_run_id",
        "type": "STRING"
      },
      {
        "description": "Timestamp of feature extraction run.",
        "mode": "REQUIRED",
        "name": "timestamp",
        "type": "TIMESTAMP"
      },
      {
        "description": "Feature extraction run metadata.",
        "mode": "REQUIRED",
        "name": "meta",
        "type": "JSON"
      },
      {
        "description": "Extracted features",
        "mode": "REQUIRED",
        "name": "features",
        "type": "JSON"
      }
    ]
  },
  "selfLink": "https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/project/datasets/dataset/tables/table",
  "tableReference": {
    "datasetId": "dataset",
    "projectId": "project",
    "tableId": "table"
  },
  "type": "TABLE"
}

Job details:

bq show -j --format=prettyjson project:region.bquxjob_562108fe_190966d854d
{
  "configuration": {
    "jobType": "QUERY",
    "query": {
      "destinationTable": {
        "datasetId": "_c7a721d4b70d2392c6643caa52c5ecf0fa067025",
        "projectId": "project",
        "tableId": "anoncb8970105fa30adbf37868493309113c88adcb284ef581320a4553c0eb2d1a66"
      },
      "priority": "INTERACTIVE",
      "query": "SELECT meta FROM `project.dataset.table` where timestamp > '2024-06-30'",
      "useLegacySql": false,
      "writeDisposition": "WRITE_TRUNCATE"
    }
  },
  "etag": "g7fZ9ss84zKxUWA8PXpjZg==",
  "id": "project:region.bquxjob_562108fe_190966d854d",
  "jobCreationReason": {
    "code": "REQUESTED"
  },
  "jobReference": {
    "jobId": "bquxjob_562108fe_190966d854d",
    "location": "region",
    "projectId": "project"
  },
  "kind": "bigquery#job",
  "principal_subject": "user:user1",
  "selfLink": "https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/project/jobs/bquxjob_562108fe_190966d854d?location=region",
  "statistics": {
    "creationTime": "1720510678481",
    "endTime": "1720510679673",
    "finalExecutionDurationMs": "681",
    "query": {
      "billingTier": 1,
      "cacheHit": false,
      "estimatedBytesProcessed": "206178878",
      "metadataCacheStatistics": {
        "tableMetadataCacheUsage": [
          {
            "explanation": "Table must be partitioned and clustered to use CMETA.",
            "tableReference": {
              "datasetId": "dataset",
              "projectId": "project",
              "tableId": "table"
            },
            "unusedReason": "OTHER_REASON"
          }
        ]
      },
      "performanceInsights": {
        "avgPreviousExecutionMs": "1358"
      },
      "queryPlan": [
        {
          "completedParallelInputs": "127",
          "computeMode": "BIGQUERY",
          "computeMsAvg": "19",
          "computeMsMax": "125",
          "computeRatioAvg": 0.05,
          "computeRatioMax": 0.32894736842105265,
          "endMs": "1720510678747",
          "id": "0",
          "name": "S00: Input",
          "parallelInputs": "127",
          "readMsAvg": "4",
          "readMsMax": "10",
          "readRatioAvg": 0.010526315789473684,
          "readRatioMax": 0.02631578947368421,
          "recordsRead": "21038",
          "recordsWritten": "21038",
          "shuffleOutputBytes": "17148416",
          "shuffleOutputBytesSpilled": "0",
          "slotMs": "287",
          "startMs": "1720510678666",
          "status": "COMPLETE",
          "steps": [
            {
              "kind": "READ",
              "substeps": [
                "$2:meta, $1:timestamp",
                "FROM project.dataset.table",
                "WHERE greater($1, 1719705600.000000000)"
              ]
            },
            {
              "kind": "WRITE",
              "substeps": [
                "$2",
                "TO __stage00_output"
              ]
            }
          ],
          "waitMsAvg": "36",
          "waitMsMax": "67",
          "waitRatioAvg": 0.09473684210526316,
          "waitRatioMax": 0.1763157894736842,
          "writeMsAvg": "2",
          "writeMsMax": "5",
          "writeRatioAvg": 0.005263157894736842,
          "writeRatioMax": 0.013157894736842105
        },
        {
          "completedParallelInputs": "1",
          "computeMode": "BIGQUERY",
          "computeMsAvg": "380",
          "computeMsMax": "380",
          "computeRatioAvg": 1,
          "computeRatioMax": 1,
          "endMs": "1720510679148",
          "id": "1",
          "inputStages": [
            "0"
          ],
          "name": "S01: Output",
          "parallelInputs": "1",
          "readMsAvg": "0",
          "readMsMax": "0",
          "readRatioAvg": 0,
          "readRatioMax": 0,
          "recordsRead": "21038",
          "recordsWritten": "21038",
          "shuffleOutputBytes": "9601578",
          "shuffleOutputBytesSpilled": "0",
          "slotMs": "526",
          "startMs": "1720510678843",
          "status": "COMPLETE",
          "steps": [
            {
              "kind": "READ",
              "substeps": [
                "$2",
                "FROM __stage00_output"
              ]
            },
            {
              "kind": "WRITE",
              "substeps": [
                "$2",
                "TO __stage01_output"
              ]
            }
          ],
          "waitMsAvg": "93",
          "waitMsMax": "93",
          "waitRatioAvg": 0.24473684210526317,
          "waitRatioMax": 0.24473684210526317,
          "writeMsAvg": "76",
          "writeMsMax": "76",
          "writeRatioAvg": 0.2,
          "writeRatioMax": 0.2
        }
      ],
      "referencedTables": [
        {
          "datasetId": "dataset",
          "projectId": "project",
          "tableId": "table"
        }
      ],
      "statementType": "SELECT",
      "timeline": [
        {
          "activeUnits": "0",
          "completedUnits": "128",
          "elapsedMs": "595",
          "estimatedRunnableUnits": "0",
          "pendingUnits": "0",
          "totalSlotMs": "814"
        },
        {
          "completedUnits": "128",
          "elapsedMs": "657",
          "estimatedRunnableUnits": "0",
          "pendingUnits": "0",
          "totalSlotMs": "814"
        }
      ],
      "totalBytesBilled": "13631488",
      "totalBytesProcessed": "13004234",
      "totalPartitionsProcessed": "0",
      "totalSlotMs": "814",
      "transferredBytes": "0"
    },
    "startTime": "1720510678570",
    "totalBytesProcessed": "13004234",
    "totalSlotMs": "814"
  },
  "status": {
    "state": "DONE"
  },
  "user_email": "user1"
}


Hi @Anton Golubev, As per the documentation BigQuery stores table data in columnar format, meaning it stores each column separately. Column-oriented databases are particularly efficient at scanning individual columns over an entire dataset. For example, if you want to compute the sum of a column over millions of rows, BigQuery can read that column data without reading every field of every row. Does this help you to resolve your issue?

@PUTHINEEDIRAMOJIRAO BigQuery somehow manage to skip unneeded data inside of the same column, while this column is neither partitioned nor clustered. how this is happens? normally the db shall perform the full scan, because the exact values in the row are unknown.

Does this link1 and link2 helps you?

@PUTHINEEDIRAMOJIRAO those texts does not explain why the database makes "short reads" instead of expected full scans (of unpartitioned data).

It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP support case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue tracker describing your issue.
